# Is it possibleto run the ejb timer after a fixed interval in Java?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.1

i want to run the ejb timer every 2 hrs between 9-18 and btw mon-sat and on friday btw 9-14 and on sat 9-13

if it is possible that on friday timers run after ever 1 hr

how can i do this with ejb timer

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class TimedBean{
    @Resource
    private TimerService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ScheduleExpression exp=new ScheduleExpression();
        exp.hour("*")
            .minute("*")
            .second("*/30");
        service.createCalendarTimer(exp);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeOut(){
        System.out.println(new Date());
        System.out.println("time out");
    }

}
```

also note that according to me this code will run after every 30 sec , but problem is it is called 2-3 times after every 30 sec
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create Timers to do all of those things:

```
ScheduleExpression exp;

exp = new ScheduleExpression().minute(0).second(0);
exp.dayOfWeek("mon-sat").hour("9,11,13,15,17");
service.createCalendarTime(exp);

exp = new ScheduleExpression().minute(0).second(0);
exp.dayOfWeek("fri").hour("9-14");
service.createCalendarTime(exp);

exp = new ScheduleExpression().minute(0).second(0);
exp.dayOfWeek("sat").hour("9,11,13");
service.createCalendarTime(exp);
```

There are some conflicts in the above timers, but that seems to be what you're asking for.  You may want to stagger them by giving each a different minute of the hour;  for instance, you may want the second to use `minute(20)` and the third to use `minute(40)`.

Reference: [`ScheduleExpression` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html)

Comment: and about secod issue timer is called 2-3 times after 30 sec according to my code

Comment: What do you mean by "combine it all"?  Those method calls should result in the same timeout method being called.  By "called 2-3 times after 30 sec" do you mean that the timeout method is called 2-3 times every 30 seconds?

Comment: if i am correct your code will create three timers and it will call on there respective time, can  this be done with only one. and yeap timeout is called 2-3 times every 30 sec

Comment: As far as I can tell, no, it cannot be done.  If I understand the EJB specification correctly, even using [@Schedules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedules.html) on a single method will create multiple Timers.  As for the timeout method being called multiple times for each scheduled timeout, I don't know why that is happening.  What Java EE server are you using?  (GlassFish, JBoss, etc.)

Comment: i am using ibm websphere 8.5

Comment: i tried on weblogic same issue there maybe some thing in my code causing this

Comment: Is it possible you are registering the timeout more than once?  Perhaps you are using both annotations and an ejb-jar.xml which contains a <timer> element?

Comment: @PreDestroy
 public void destroy()
 {
  WriteToFile("Destroy on " +getTimeStamp());
  for(Timer timer :service.getTimers())
  {
   timer.cancel();
  }
 }                           this solved the issue also i     made some changes in int Timer timer as        destoy(); service.createCalendarTimer(exp,new TimerConfig("TimerScheduler",false));

Comment: now i need to know that timers are not called on constant interval some minor difference like between different timeout the  the milli sec is 29983 sometimes 29987 , 29984 etc is this by design or i am  missing something?